# Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator deletes versions of media

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

I am adding images to the Media Library using the "Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator" and the "CreateFromStream"-function.
Everything seems to work fine except that everytime I add a new image to an already existing image item the old image is overwritten, I would like to create a new version instead and add the new image to the new version, keeping the old version and image. The images should be based on an "unversioned" template as images are shared between languages.

I have tried programmatically adding a new version prior to adding new media but the new version is deleted after running CreateFromStream().

I have also tried the different MediaCreatorOptions "Versioned" and "KeepExisting" but it doesn't help me.

It is possible to do this using SheerUI so I guess it should be possible.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Or maybe if someone has any good code that adds media to the library without using MediaCreator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved it.

```
Media media = MediaManager.GetMedia(myOldMediaItem);
media.SetStream(memoryStream, extension);
```

This code does not delete any previous versions, off course I need to add the new versions before.