# In Sitecore 7.5 how to programmatically create media items with language versioning?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.5, sitecore-media-library

I want to be able to create/update media items in code and also use language versioning.  Here are more specifics.  I have a Product content item.  When that item is saved I want to be able to generate a PDF version of that item and save it to the media library.  If the PDF version already exists in the media library I need to be able to update it.  In addition this is a multi-language site.  So if someone saves the French version of the Product content item I need to be able to generate the French version of the PDF and only save/update the French version of the associated PDF in the media library - not touch any of the other language versions of the PDF.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  The code that I have currently does the following:  if I save the English version of the Product then it creates and English version of the PDF.  But then if I save the French version of the Product, it creates a French version of the PDF and removes the English version of the PDF.

Anyone know how to do this?

```
    public static Item AddMediaItem(byte[] fileBuffer, string fullMediaPath, string fileNameWithExtension, string title, Language language)
    {
        try
        {
            var db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
            var options = new MediaCreatorOptions();
            options.FileBased = false;
            options.IncludeExtensionInItemName = false;
            options.KeepExisting = false;
            options.Versioned = true;
            options.Destination = fullMediaPath;
            options.Database = db;
            options.Language = language;

            var creator = new MediaCreator();
            var fileStream = new MemoryStream(fileBuffer);

            var pdfItem = db.GetItem(fullMediaPath, language);
            if (pdfItem != null)
            {
                var updatedItem = creator.AttachStreamToMediaItem(fileStream, fullMediaPath, fileNameWithExtension,
                    options);
                updatedItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
                updatedItem.Fields["Title"].Value = title;
                updatedItem.Editing.EndEdit();
                return updatedItem;
            }
            else
            {
                //Create a new item
                var newItem = creator.CreateFromStream(fileStream, fileNameWithExtension, options);
                newItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
                newItem.Fields["Title"].Value = title;
                newItem.Editing.EndEdit();
                return newItem;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are Unversioned and Versioned Media templates, be sure you use the Versioned one. Else the media is a Shared Field.

Comment: Well, in my code I don't specify the template at all.  I am using the MediaCreator and if you see in the options I am specifying options.Versioned = true.  So I assume that is correct.  And I do notice that the item that gets created does use the Versioned Media template for PDFs.  So I think that part is correct.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734834/sitecore-resources-media-mediacreator-deletes-versions-of-media

Comment: Thanks so much @JanBluemink for pointing me to that post.  I was able to modify my code and now it is working the way I need it to!

Comment: One of my ongoing frustrations with Sitecore is that it is always difficult to find the "proper" way of doing something in code.  The documentation of their API leaves a lot to be desired.  Usually you have to hunt through blog posts or Stack Overflow to find what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @JanBluemink for pointing me in the right direction. I found the right approach in the following article: [Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator deletes versions of media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734834/sitecore-resources-media-mediacreator-deletes-versions-of-media).  I just had to modify the code to use MediaManager instead of MediaCreator when updating.

```
    public static Item AddMediaItem(byte[] fileBuffer, string fullMediaPath, string fileNameWithExtension, string title, Language language)
    {
        try
        {
            var db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
            var options = new MediaCreatorOptions();
            options.FileBased = false;
            options.IncludeExtensionInItemName = false;
            options.KeepExisting = false;
            options.Versioned = true;
            options.Destination = fullMediaPath;
            options.Database = db;
            options.Language = language;

            var creator = new MediaCreator();
            var fileStream = new MemoryStream(fileBuffer);

            var pdfItem = db.GetItem(fullMediaPath, language);
            if (pdfItem != null)
            {
                var mediaItem = new MediaItem(pdfItem);
                var media = MediaManager.GetMedia(mediaItem);
                media.SetStream(fileStream, "pdf");

                pdfItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
                pdfItem.Fields["Title"].Value = title;
                pdfItem.Editing.EndEdit();
                return pdfItem;
            }
            else
            {
                //Create a new item
                var newItem = creator.CreateFromStream(fileStream, fileNameWithExtension, options);
                newItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
                newItem.Fields["Title"].Value = title;
                newItem.Editing.EndEdit();
                return newItem;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add couple of more lines for updating media item stored in File System with versioning.

```
if (mediaItem.FileBased)
        {
            string uniqueFilename = FileUtil.GetUniqueFilename(FileUtil.MakePath(Settings.Media.FileFolder, MediaManager.Creator.GetMediaStorageFolder(mediaItem.ID, fileshortname)));
            using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
            {
                mediaItem.BeginEdit();
                mediaItem.FilePath = uniqueFilename;
                mediaItem.EndEdit();
            }
        }
        Media media = MediaManager.GetMedia(mediaItem);
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            media.SetStream(stream, FileUtil.GetExtension(fileshortname));
        }`
```